# Proper driver.quit() to enable reopening the driver

Tags: python, selenium, bots

After my bot is done doing it's job I initiate `driver.quit()` to terminate the session, so I can start a new one by opening the driver again after some time, but I get the following error:

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=56717): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/042df57c7e963e8f582735ae8242a5df/window (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001BDB7117F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

My code:

```
    if loopNumber == 15:
        timeStop = timeit.default_timer()
        execution_time = timeStop - timeStart
        print("Program Executed in "+str(execution_time/60)+" Minutes") # It returns time in seconds
        driver.stop_client()
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(600)
```

after 600 seconds I want to open the webdriver again but this error is triggered. What will be the proper way to gracefully close webdriver and start it again?

Comment: just change that to `driver.close()` and see if that helps.

Comment: The reason why I didn't use driver.close() is because I have 2 tabs and driver.close() just closes the opened tab.

Comment: @Emoyaki you need to provide more information then. Is the 2nd tab also being controlled by webdriver? Are you controlling it from the same program?

Comment: @Dillanm Yes, basically my tool sends messages and the 1st tab is a sheet from where the bot gets the names of the people I want to message and the 2nd tab is where it sends the messages

Answer (score 2):

If you want to end the process and start a new session again, you need to reinitialize driver object.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.close() # or driver.quit()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

But you can also use same session to open a new URL.
Get the Child window and close the same.
Focus on the parent window and do `driver.get(URL)` again.

Note: The browser does not close.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com")
#Code to close the child window and focus on the parent window.
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```